# Is this C++ template declaration genuinely incorrect or is my compiler mucking up?

Tags: c++

***Edit: Thank you for your answers! Like I said, this is code provided for a class, so the namespace and name of the function were included. I'm glad to understand what exactly namespace std entails though, and I've included your inputs as comments within my answer (though my answer remains unchanged).***

The code below includes the piece I created. This is for a class, so this is the *only* part that I need judged. My compiler isn't running it **(ambiguous calls to overloaded function)** but I feel like this is correct.

```
template <class data_type>
void swap(data_type &a, data_type &b) //swaps 2 variables
{
   data_type c; //temp variable
   c = a;
   a = b;
   b = c;
}
```

Here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class data_type>
void swap(data_type &a, data_type &b) //swaps variables
{
   data_type c;
   c = a;
   a = b;
   b = c;
}

int main( )
{
    string x = "first", y = "second";
    int m = 10, n = 20;
    char q = 'Q', r = 'R';

    cout<<"x before swap called = "<<x<<" and y before swap called = "
<<y<<endl;
    swap(x,y);
    cout<<"x after swap called = "<<x<<" and y after swap called = "
<<y<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<"m before swap called = "<<m<<" and n before swap called = "
<<n<<endl;
    swap(m,n);
    cout<<"m after swap called = "<<m<<" and n after swap called = "
<<n<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<"q before swap called = "<<q<<" and r before swap called = "  
<<r<<endl;
    swap(q,r);
    cout<<"q after swap called = "<<q<<" and r after swap called = "   
<<r<<endl<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is why you do not use `using namespace std;`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: To be blatantly obvious, the library function `std::swap` is conflicting with your `swap` because you included all the symbols from `std`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard library comes with a template `std::swap` (see [cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)), and you are defining your own `swap`-template function. So far no problem, but once you declare `using namespace std`, any use of `swap` is ambiguous, since the compiler cannot decide whether to take `std::swap` or your own `swap`.

So, as mentioned already by others, avoid `using namespace std` statement.

Additionally, you could think of declaring "your" `swap` in an own namespace, like:

```
namespace class1_exercise {

    template <class data_type>
    void swap(data_type &a, data_type &b) //swaps variables
    {
        data_type c;
        c = a;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }
}
```

Thereby, you can make the distinction between "your" swap and the std::swap even more explicit:

```
std::swap(x,y);
// versus:
class1_exercise::swap(x,y);
```

Answer (score 4):

It's you.

```
//using namespace std;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
```

Comment: So my code is fine? Like I said, that part is included by the instructor and is not to be altered. The question is basically how would you turn overloaded functions given into a template function, and I've done that correctly, yes?

Comment: @user135536 show your instructor this answer. `using namespace std;` is a *really bad idea* in real code.

Answer (score 2):

This is the cause of the error

```
using namespace std;
```

It's a really really really bad practice to declare **"using namespace std"**
Using the namespace will pull things in that you don't want

There are two alternate solutions

**ONE**

```
using std::cout; 
cout << "Values:";
```

**TWO** (i'll suggest this one)

```
std::cout << "Values:";
```

Note : you could change the name of your swap function but it's always better to adapt a better way so you encounter fewer problems in future